# find all two digit numbers with the property that if i sum the digits and add this sum to the product of the digits, i get the number.

Tags: number-theory

> find all two digit numbers with the property that if i sum the digits
>   and add this sum to the product of the digits, i get the number.

I noticed that every number that ends with $9$ works but i would like to know the reason behind this.

for example:

$19 \rightarrow 1+9=10 \rightarrow 10+(9 \times 1)=19$

Also works for $29,39,\ldots,89,99$

Any reason why this works?

Comment: It is not true that $1+9 = 10 + (9\times 1)$.  I understand what you meant, but that is certainly not standard use of notation and in many contexts it can lead to confusion. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: you are right, lemme edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x+y + xy=10x + y\implies 9x=xy$

If $x\ne 0$ then $y=9$

Comment: Made so much sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well to answer your second question about why this works:

We can write a two-digit number as $10t+u$ where $t \leq 9$ is the integer in the tens place and $u \leq 9$ is the integer in the ones place. So your question leads to:

$10t+u = t+u+tu$

$9t = tu$

$u=9$

So it's clear that the unit digit must be a 9 and that works for all integers $t \in \left\lbrace 1,2, \cdots, 9 \right\rbrace$